# Dismiss Mail composer on launch of the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

If suppose user has opened a mail composer inside the app and before closing mail composer, goes background. And next time when he launches the app, I wish to dismiss the mail composer. How do I check whether mail composer is present upfront and how do I dismiss it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that presents the mail composer should register for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification.

Upon receipt of the notification, you can dismiss the mail composer.

No need to wait until the user launches the app again. Do it when the app enters the background.

Comment: Never thought of it closing while going background. Works like a charm. Thanks.